# My Laravel 5.4 Logged in User Sessions wont persist

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I'm having this weird issue with my app, it can't persist logged in user session using the Auth facade. Example, in my header view I put logged in user data as :

```
@if (Auth::check())
    <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       <img src="{{route('getphoto', Auth::user()->image)}}" alt="" />
       {{ Auth::user()->name }}
       <span class="caret"></span>
       </button>
     </div>
@else
     <div class="btn-group">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Not Logged In
       </button>
     </div>
@endif
```

At the first time after login the logged in user data in the header like photo and name will be displayed correctly, but after I refresh or moving to another page they disappear and indicate that the user is not logged in. I don't know what I did wrong, all I did with user login related function is just changing the email to username. How do I solve this ? I'm using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2):

You need to set correct permissions for the `storage` directory:

```
chmod -R 755 storage
```

> After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the `storage` and the `bootstrap/cache` directories should be writable by your web server.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/installation

Comment: @SandraVioletta no. It's Unix command, so you should run it from the terminal.

Comment: Unix ? Is there windows equivalent for that command ? and my app is running on localhost using XAMPP so I'm not using any real server yet

Comment: @SandraVioletta in Window it's different, you can google it. Or you can install git bash, use `cd` command to go to the Laravel project root directory and run the command.

Comment: So, I did run the command using cygwin and got this following error

Comment: `fopen(C:\xampp\htdocs\mk2\storage\framework/sessions/cXbIWi94avDoaqULr5P3SOAFKW1yBTmI4l1vUOqj): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: @SandraVioletta try to use 777 instead of 755. This might help, but never do that on the production server. If it'll not help, you'll need to learn how to work with permissions in a specific version of Windows that you use.